# Why i in for loop takes usize instead of being u64?

Tags: for-loop, rust

I am new into Rust and I have encountered the following issue. The following code compiles without problems, but crashes/panics during runtime leaving me with the following message: "**attempt to add with overflow**".

Here is the mentioned snippet:

```
let mut fib:[u64; 200] = [1; 200];


for i in 2..fib.len() {
   fib[i] = fib[i - 2] + fib[i - 1];
}

for i in 0..fib.len() {
   print!("{}, ", fib[i]);
}
```

I can't understand why the i variable looks to be of type **usize** and not of type **u64**.
Thanks for your time and explanation. Somehow I could not find proper information on this.

Comment: In your 2nd `for`, did you mean `0` or `1`?

Comment: Note that on 64-bit computers, `usize` and `u64` are the same.

Comment: "why the i variable looks to be of type usize and not of type u64" Because `fib.len()` is of type `usize` (not that it makes a difference, as Jmb's comment says).

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Well, I thought the fib.len() will be of type u64. But as Jmb mentioned, they are actually the same on 64-bit PC which is my case as well.

Comment: @ivo it's always `usize`, whatever the type of array or slice members: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.len If you search for other `len()` methods https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html?search=len, you'll find they return `usize` too...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In iteration `i = 93`, the values you are trying to add are `fib[91] = 7540113804746346429` and `fib[92] = 12200160415121876738`.

The result of this is larger than 2<sup>64</sup>−1, so overflows the `u64` type and the code panics.

This has nothing to do with the type of `i`.

Comment: yes, they can built it in release where overflow checks are removed and run it. then it won't panic. just overflow and start over.

Comment: Thanks all to you guys, I forgot completely those Fibonacci numbers can get too big very quickly. Thanks for your time and effort.